# Documentation for PS1 format

Tags: bash, terminal

I see lots of tutorials for adjusting the appearance of the prompt in bash (like [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)), but where can I find the documentation for the format of the `PS1` variable?

Answer (score 5):

Type `info bash` (if you have the "bash" info documentation installed on your system), search for `PS1`, then follow the link to `*Note Controlling a Prompt::`.

That section of the manual is online [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html).